# capture an array inside a queue

Tags: swift, closures, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following function that is doing work in the background. 
Every work unit is added to a concurrent work queue.
Then the result is added to an array (sharedArray).

However the array never has the correct amount of values. It's always 1. That is probably because the array gets copied every time. How can I get a reference to the array instead?

```
//input
let testValues = ["a","b","c"]
dispatch_async(self.concurrentQueue) {

//pool results
let sharedResourceQueue = dispatch_queue_create("processed", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL) //protect the shared resource
var sharedArray : [String] = []

// processing
autoreleasepool { //only usefull for obj-c and cocoa classes
    for value in testValues
    {
        self.process(value) { processedValue in
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { println(processedValue) } //intermediate callback
           dispatch_sync(sharedResourceQueue) { 
                  sharedArray.append(value);
                  println("tally \(sharedArray.count) | \(sharedArray)")
               }    
            }
        }
    }

dispatch_sync(sharedResourceQueue) {}//wait for completion

//save results and report back
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {println(sharedArray)}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) swift should automatically determine if it needs to capture by reference or value:

> Swift determines what should be captured by reference and what should
>   be copied by value. You don’t need to annotate amount or runningTotal
>   to say that they can be used within the nested incrementer function.
>   Swift also handles all memory management involved in disposing of
>   runningTotal when it is no longer needed by the incrementer function.

However, this doesn't appear to be working in your case.

Suggest you try including a weak reference to the array in a capture list:

```
    dispatch_sync(sharedResourceQueue) { 
       [weak sharedArray] in                  
       sharedArray.append(value);
       println("tally \(sharedArray.count) | \(sharedArray)")
   }
```

Comment: unowned and weak "cannot be applied to non-class type".

[sharedArray] gives "immutable value of type [string] only has mutating members named append"